# Python package anomoly

Tags: ros, python, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
from std_msgs.msg import String
```

when ROS encounters a statement like the one above, where does it search, to obtain String class? I check $PYTHONPATH and it doesn't seem like the class exists in a file located in that path. I searched the ROS package std_msgs..but it only shows a folder msg that has the String.msg file in it. I don't see any module called 'msg' in which I expect to find the 'String' class..

Could someone please tell me whats going on? Am I missing something fundamental or are things really twisted a little bit.. ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28432/python-package-anomoly/) by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look in the `std_msgs` package in the src directory. When messages are generated, the resulting python module is placed in the src folder in a subdirectory with the same name as the package. So the full file path on my machine is:

```
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/messages/std_msgs/src/std_msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To add to what DimitriProsser said, when you do `roslib.load_manifest('my_package')`, it alters your `sys.path` and add the appropriate paths so python is able to do the imports.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1